# MYSQL query LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a query that is pulling from a table and left joining on another table. If I remove the LEFT JOIN, it returns ten records due to a LIMIT 10 in the query. When I add a LEFT JOIN, it is only returning the one record that has a match in the joined table.

How can I get it to return all ten records include the column from the other table if there is a match but if there is no match leave the column blank?

Here are the two versions of the query, one without and one with LEFT JOIN:

Version 1: Returns 10 records:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.first,d.last,d.descript,d.profilepic,d.userid,d.id   
FROM demo `d`";
$sql.=" LIMIT 10";
```

Version 1: Returns 1 Record.  Of the 10 records, only has a match in points

```
$sql = "SELECT d.first,d.last,d.descript,d.profilepic,d.userid,d.id,SUM(p.points) AS points 
FROM demo `d` 
LEFT JOIN points `p` 
ON p.userid = d.userid";
$sql.=" LIMIT 10";
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Sample data would really help here.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] Show what reasonable parts of this you can do. How is what you want related to some queries you can write? Also your writing is unclear. Use enough words & references to parts of examples. Not just some of those words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add group by

```
SELECT d.first,d.last,d.descript,d.profilepic,d.userid,d.id,SUM(p.points) AS points 
FROM demo `d` 
LEFT JOIN points `p` 
ON p.userid = d.userid
group by d.id
```

Comment: `GROUP BY d.id` should be sufficient most likely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, but just because it's mysql. For other databases, it will give error

Comment: @JayJodiwal Not true.  Postgres, which is closest to the ANSI standard, also supports `GROUP BY` with functional dependencies.  The issue here is not only full group by, it's something which the ANSI standard supports.

Comment: @JayJodiwal good time to read this : http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html  :-)

Comment: GROUP BY d.id worked. If you'd like to put in an answer I will mark it as correct.